# pie charts are overlapping in php page

Tags: javascript, php, charts

With `<canvas>` and JavaScript in php,I am trying to draw multiple pie charts.But charts are overlapping.

Here my javascript code:

```
printf('<script type="text/javascript">');
?>
function drawPie(data)
{
    var ctx = $("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var piedata = [];
    $.each(data,function(i,val){
       piedata.push({value:val.count,color:val.color,label:val.status});
    });
    new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata);
 }
<?php
printf('</script>');
```

PHP code:

```
$data  = statusPool($pool);//fetching database values(array() of  label and count )
printf('<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>');

$data3 = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">    drawPie('.$data3.');    </script>';
printf( '<table ><tr>' );

$poolArray =array(//some values) 

$chartCount = 0;
foreach ( $poolArray as $pool ) 
{
     if ($chartCount == 2) 
     {
            printf('</tr><tr>');
            $chartCount = 0;
     }

     printf('<td style="text-align: center;"><canvas id="mycanvas"width="256" height="256"></canvas>');
     $data = statusPool($pool);
     $data3 = json_encode($data2, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">    drawPie(' . $data3 . ');</script>';

     $chartCount++;
     printf('</a></td>')
 }
 printf( '</tr></table>' );
```

First `<canvas>` is for big pie chart and other small charts will come in table.

But all the charts are overlapped.

Can you tell me how to get rid of that overlapping.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot or JS fiddle illustrating your problem? It would make  understanding your code much easier. Thanks in advance!

Comment: All the charts are overlapped with in the same canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the screenshot! The problem, as far as I can see, is, that all of your canvas elements have the same ID "mycanvas". In HTML, all objects are supposed to have an unique ID (if you give one to them at all). Classes can be used for more than one object, and one object can have multiple classes. It is like all employees of a company usually have different names (id) to identify them, but several people can be assigned a specific team (class) and people can also be in more than one team. If people have the same name, it usually causes confusion in the office. You have the same problem here.

To fix it, give every canvas an unique id. This could look similar to this:

```
echo '<td style="text-align: center;"><canvas id="pie-canvas-'
   . $canvasId
   . '"width="256" height="256"></canvas>';
```

Pass the ID you gave to your canvas to the function that is drawing it.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">drawPie('
   . $canvasId
   . ', '
   . $data3
   . ');</script>';
```

I don't really know what is in `$data2` or `$data3`, but I assume it also contains something like an ID that you could use for this purpose. If not, let the loop iterate a variable and use its value as ID. When you add the script to draw the current pi in the loop, pass the ID as parameter (if you do not already do it with `$data3`) and select the particular canvas from the document using

```
function drawPie(canvasId, data) {
    [...]
    var ctx = $("#pie-canvas-" + canvasId).getContext("2d");
    [...]
}
```

Btw. you have some errors in your code like missing semicolons, unopened or unclosed HTML tags, etc.

Comment: @Jonathan.Thanks for the answer.I tried out your code.It is good idea.But in JS code `var ctx = $("#pie-canvas-" . $canvasId).getContext("2d");` it shows error.How to pass $canvasId into JS?.Can you please share your exercises on this using JS fiddle?

Comment: I am sorry, the propper way to combine strings in JS is using a *plus*. I confused it with PHP, where you use a *dot*. I corrected it in the example code above.

I also added some further code examples. Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: @Jonathan.Thank you so much.It is working now.One more help please.In the function drawPie() how can I give legend and title for each pie chart?

Comment: Currently label for each slice is not visible(Only on mouse over)

Comment: Glad I could help! Am I understanding you right, that you want to put the legend for your chart in the canvas, too? Then this heavily depends on the function that is actually drawing the chart (in your case a method of the class Chart or Pie). You can also draw on or add text to the canvas after `new Chart(ctx).Pie(piedata);` using the normal drawing methods of JavaScript for canvas elements. If you need precise help on this, I suggest to open up a new question where you show us some of the code that is drawing your pie-chart on the canvas.